# Declare a string

Tags: java, string, initialization

what is the difference between :

```
String s1;
```

And

```
String s1 = new string();
```

How does the memory operate?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: No homework.. Just for me

Comment: @user7 The OP isn't asking about the string pool.  In this case, the first statement doesn't create an object at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1;
```

Is either:

1. An uninitialized local variable. Attempting to use `s1` without first assigning a value will result in a compilation error.
2. An uninitialized field. It will have a default value (`null`).

---

```
String s1 = new String();
```

Is a variable or field initialized to an empty string;

---

The first declares an identifier or field for later use, while the second allocates and assigns a value (empty string) to the identifier.

Comment: "Attempting to use s1 without first assigning a value will result in a compilation error." Not necessarily - it only will if it is a local variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner - good point, will add that too.